# Parent-child relationship in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, recursion, promise, parent-child

Ok guys here is the thing.

I have a mongo data base which contains 3 collections:

- GeoLevels
- GeoPlaces
- Point Of Interest

GeoPlaces are linked together by a parent-child relationship (It's a tree). So every GeoPlace have a parent except those at the top of the tree.

PoI have a geography field that contains an array of GeoPlaces references (by checking the geoPlace.ParentId).

I have to check if the geography references to GeoPlaces form a tree too. And if it does, I also have to check if that tree is a sub-part of the more general GeoPlaces tree.

So what I do is get a cursor of the mongo PoI collection. Iterate through it then map the content of the geography array to get the geoPlace reference of it.

Then, I try to do a recursive by creating a function getParent that take a geoPlace ID as an arg and return his parent in a parentsArr.

Then i recursively return the same function with the new parentId argument. So that it can fill my parentsArr until there is no more parentId defined in my chain (aka I'm at the top of the tree, no more parent).

Here is the code:

```
    const getParents = (cp, geoRef, parentsArr, poiId, geoIndex) => {

    let gpFromPOI = GeoPlaces.findOne({_id: geoRef});

    gpFromPOI.then((gp) => {
      if(gp){
        if(parentsArr){
          parentsArr.push(gp._id );
        }
        if(gp.ParentId){

          if(parentsArr.indexOf(gp.ParentId) > -1){
            parentsArr.push(gp.ParentId)
            return cp;
          }

          return cp.then(() => {
            return GeoPlaces.findOne({_id: gp.ParentId})
              .then((parentId) => {
                if(parentId && parentId.ParentId != null){
                  return getParents(cp, parentId.ParentId, parentsArr );
                }
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.error('Error promise  : ', err)
              })
          }) 
        } else {
          return;
        }

      }
    })

    return cp;
  }


  const resolveParent = async (geoRef, poiId, geoIndex) => {

    const parentsArr = [];
    let cp = Q();

    await getParents(cp, geoRef, parentsArr, poiId, geoIndex);


    return parentsArr;
  }

  const getGeographyGenealogy = async () => {
    let cursor = PoI.find({}).project({Geographies:1});
    let deferred = Q.defer();

    cursor.forEach((poi) => {
      if (poi){

        if (poi.Geographies){
          poi.Geographies.map(async (geoRef, geoIndex) => {
            let genealogy = await resolveParent(geoRef._id, poi._id, geoIndex);
          });
        }
      }
    }, (err) => {
      if(err){
        console.error('Error', err )
      }
      cursor.close().then(() => {
        deferred.resolve();
      })
    })
    return deferred.promise
      .then(() => {

      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Err Promise : ', err)
      })
  }

  await getGeographyGenealogy();
```

The problem is that my parentsArr return only a single value.
ie:

Genealogy for PoI ( 5847e7451ab03b73fe07cebb ) geography[2] ==> [ 595a5f73cac8c815d8947e5a ]

Where the array after '==>' should contain the id of the references, the id of the parent reference, the id of the parent of the parent reference, etc until there is no more parent.

Any idea ?

ps: an output of the geoPlace:

```
    { _id: 58a47e1bacc9ab155c49b48f,
      Version: null,
      CreatedAt: 
        [ Long { _bsontype: 'Long', low_: -1943318939, high_: 148133309},0 ],
      UpdatedAt: 
        [ Long { _bsontype: 'Long', low_: -1943318939, high_: 148133309},0 ],
      Deleted: false,
      Name: 'NORTH',
      LevelId: 56fbcd970000000000000003,
      ParentId: 58a47e1bacc9ab155c49b3etf,
      Latitude: null,
      Longitude: null,
      CreatedBy: 'xxx',
      UpdatedBy: 'xxx' }
```

Comment: With so many relationships, I'm curious why you're using a mongo database  vs using a relational database.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by passing around that `cp` variable?

Comment: cp is a chain of promises. It get resolve when the cursor is closed.


@dvsoukup : I don't own the db, i just have to make test on it.

Comment: You need to fix a few nonsenses : 
(1) `cp` is unnecessary, `getParents()` can simply return the promise arising from `GeoPlaces.findOne().then(...)`; 
(2) `cursor.forEach()` has the signature `cursor.forEach(function)`; 
(3) in `poi.Geographies.map(...)`, nothing beneficial is done with the promise returned by `resolveParent()`.